# External php script drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Hi I have a problem while setting an external php script. My external php script code is here:

```
<?php
$currdir = getcwd();
//Print "Current dir: $currdir <br/>";
//echo "Document root: " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "<br/>";
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/home/");
require_once("./includes/bootstrap.inc");
//until here works fine
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
    //500 internal server error
?>
```

However there is some problems with drupal_bootstrap function that gives me an 500 server internal error. Do you know any problems relating to what I am experiencing here. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out the answer. I need to change the base_url in settings.php to my current one. Everything works like a charm. Here is the source for people who need it : https://drupal.org/node/575002

Comment: Now I got a problem with AJAX call, the session id seems to changed when I call the ajax on the same php file. Anyone got this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to make it work with ajax, you need to login the user to drupal also, and then do the ajax with module in Drupal. That is the only way you can get the session ID with ajax.